# переопределение toString в иерахии классов Java

Tags: java, ооп

в абстрактном классе:

```
public String toString() {
        return "distance = " + String.format("%.3f", way) +
                " moving speed = " + String.format("%.3f", SPEED) 
    }
```

в потомке от абстрактного:

```
public String toString() {
                return "RideOnLine: " + super.toString();
    }
```

в потомке от потомка:

```
public String toString() {
                return "RideOnCurve: " + super.toString();
    }
```

в итоге вывод: RideOnCurve: *RideOnLine:* distance = 60,000 moving speed = 60,000.
Подскажите как грамотно сделать, чтобы не было строки(курсивом) от потомка абстрактного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама суть переопределения методов в том, чтобы все дети класса-родителя, переопределившего какой-либо метод, видели у себя "новую" версию метода.

Вы же хотите иметь возможность получить "чистый" результат метода `toString()` абстрактного класса у всех потомков по иерархии. Для этого вынесите этот метод отдельно (при необходимости - в финальный) и используйте в потомках его. Пример реализации:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    private float way = 60000;
    private float SPEED = 60000;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return formatData();
    }

    protected final String formatData() {
        return String.format("distance = %.3f moving speed = %.3f", way, SPEED);
    }
}

class Parent extends AbstractClass {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RideOnLine: " + formatData();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RideOnCurve: " + formatData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Abstract {
  protected String getInfo() {
    return "distance = " + String.format("%.3f", way) +
            " moving speed = " + String.format("%.3f", SPEED);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getInfo(); 
  }
}

class Child1 extends Abstract {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "RideOnLine: " + getInfo();
  }
}

class Child2 extends Child1 {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "RideOnCurve: " + super.toString();
  }
}
```

Или

```
class Abstract {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "distance = " + String.format("%.3f", way) +
            " moving speed = " + String.format("%.3f", SPEED);
  }
}

class Child1 extends Abstract {
  protected String getPrefix() {
    return "RideOnLine: ";
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getPrefix() + super.toString();
  }
}

class Child2 extends Child1 {
  @Override
  protected String getPrefix() {
    return "RideOnCurve: ";
  }
}
```